# Как фиксировано задать массив?

Tags: c, visual-studio, c++, visual-c++

Как фиксировано задать массив? Без всяких циклов.
Делаю так:

```
int A[100]=[34,9,22,4,10,2,0,0,0,10,9,9,8,5,3,8,3,4,13,20,8,0,26,0,20,30,7,26,7,20,15,8,17,3,17,3,1,16,1,12,13,35,7,4,6,51,6,12,16,10,0,2,12,9,10,33,11,18,0,3,14,1,24,4,17,12,6,8,7,6,18,1,7,11,14,38,19,48,5,4,0,4,29,23,3,1,37,9,36,46,2,23,12,8,1,8,9,8,0,16];
```

Как надо?

Comment: И работает?

Comment: Потому что это не Паскаль, а Си. `{}` же!

Comment: Интересный подход к изучению методом тыка...

Comment: Блин. Вроде 100500 разных вариантов пробовал прежде чем написать... Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Содержимое массива заключите в фигурные скобки.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{
  int A[10] = {1,2,3};
  int n = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]), i;

  printf ("array A size = %d elements\n",n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf ("A[%d] = %d\n",i,A[i]);

  int B[] = {10,20,30};
  n = sizeof(B)/sizeof(B[0]);

  printf ("array B size = %d elements\n",n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf ("B[%d] = %d\n",i,B[i]);

  return 0;
}

c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc a.c
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a
array A size = 10 elements
A[0] = 1
A[1] = 2
A[2] = 3
A[3] = 0
A[4] = 0
A[5] = 0
A[6] = 0
A[7] = 0
A[8] = 0
A[9] = 0
array B size = 3 elements
B[0] = 10
B[1] = 20
B[2] = 30
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $
```

Проинициализированы, как написали в инициализации - первые три. Для массива B размер не указан, он делается равным количеству инициализаторов.